# Laravel route returns wrong route

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I tried to change url from .env and app config file, no success

```
$req = Request::create('/api/auth/login', 'POST', [
    "user" => $request->user,
    "password" => $request->password,
]);

$redirect = route('home'); // http://127.0.0.1:8000/home

$res = app()->handle($req);

$redirect = route('home'); // http://localhost/home
```

Comment: What happens when you hit `/api/auth/login` ?

Comment: @Gammer Go to the authenticate function from api and return response with token json

Comment: What exactly you want do ?

Comment: @Gammer I need that `route('home')` returns 127.0.0.1:8000 instead of localhost

Comment: It will return 127.0.0.1:8000 because your application is running on port 8000, Plus 127.0.0.1 = localhost, Your actual local IP is 127.0.0.1 and on top of that is localhost, Please clear your concepts.

Comment: If you only need localhost without any port then your should setup a virtualhost, P.S try localhost:8080 or 127.0.0.1:8000 are the same, It will return the same applications which should be only running on 8000 port.